# Unexplained Aborted XHR

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, html2canvas

I have a menu item that, when clicked, captures a screenshot of the website and sends it to a backing bean.  It uses the `html2canvas` library.  The problem is that I'm getting random aborted XHRs and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code for the menu item:

```
<p:submenu label="Print" id="print">
        <p:menuitem value="Print Map in PDF" onclick="printMapPDF();"/>     
</p:submenu>
```

Here is the code for the function:

```
function printMapPDF() {

    console.log("test 1");

    html2canvas($('#mainForm\\:map'), {
        allowTaint : true,
        useCORS : true,
        onrendered : function(canvas) {
            console.log("test 2");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var hidden = document.getElementById('mainForm:dataURLfield');
            hidden.setAttribute('value', dataURL);
            hidden.onchange();  
        }
    });

    console.log("test 3");

    return true;
}
```

`'test 1'` and `'test 3'` appear on the console.  Then, when the image is rendered, it calls the callback function, the XHR is aborted, and finally `'test 2'` appears.  I suppose the error must be happening when `html2canvas` is called, but I don't know what to do about this.

Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occasional Ajax error when using html2canvas, no status code, no response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677735/occasional-ajax-error-when-using-html2canvas-no-status-code-no-response)

Comment: Why this duplicate of **your own** question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677735/occasional-ajax-error-when-using-html2canvas-no-status-code-no-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's aborted because `<p:menuitem>` navigates to its (default) target URL. Simply let the `onclick` `return false;` to prevent the element from performing its default click behavior (usually, refreshing the current page).

```
<p:menuitem ... onclick="printMapPDF(); return false;" />
```

When the navigation happens before the ajax request gets sent, then you'll obviously get exactly this problem of an aborted XHR.

---

That said, it's worth the effort to take a step back from JSF and learn some basic [HTML](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/) and [JavaScript](http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/) first. Your concrete problem is not JSF related. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. You'd have had exactly the same problem when having a copy of JSF-generated HTML output in a plain `.html` file and the question would easily be answerable by [html](/questions/tagged/html)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) users.